# ReactNative-Expo: Dropped frames with brand new app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Brand new Expo App is showing that some frames are being dropped, is this normal/expected behavior? (It doesn't feel like performance is hindered).

I am running this on actual physical device (Android OnePlus8, Snapdragon 865 chip).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## This is absolutely normal.

If you app is faster/smotther your app will drop less frames. But also keep in mind that, if you are emulating the phone on a slow computer then you will notice much more frames dropped due to lower performance.

Same as all of our physical devices have performance differences. So, its normal that some frames will be dropped.

I am running this brand new expo project on actual physical device (Android A20s)

[image]